# Reversing a block hash of SHA-1 with known Plaintext?

Tags: hash, sha, sha256, sha2, known-plaintext-attack

Is it possible to reverse the hashing of a block in a Datastream fed to an SHA1 if the plaintext for that block is known? If it is not possible (which I assume) does it make attacks to retrieve the state easier?

An example what I'm trying to figure out:
The following data is known:

- suffix1
- The result of SHA1(secret + suffix1)
- The length of secret, which happens to be exactly 512 bit (ie a full SHA block)

Now what I'd like to figure out is **SHA1(secret + suffix2)** (a different known suffix)

(+ means String concatenation)

(suffix1 is known but can not be manipulated a length extension attack is (probably (?)) not possible)

Is this possible? Is there any research on doing this or is it just plain out impossible? If it is possible: Does this also apply to the SHA-2 family?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no known attack against SHA-1 that would help in determining the value of `secret`. However, this scheme *is* vulnerable to length-extension attacks. Knowing `SHA-1(s)`, you can easily find the padding `p`, and from there is is trivial to calculate the value of `SHA-1(s + p + anything)`, even though you don't know `s`.

Comment: Thank you. However as I already mentioned I can not modify suffix1 in such a way to include the padding. I'm also not trying to retrieve secret (which is probably rather hard) what I'm trying to find is SHA-1(secret + anything) without special requirements on anything (ie. that is has to start with a SHA-1 padding)

Comment: I think you have the same question I had before http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8496/reversing-sha1-dont-know-the-correct-term

Comment: For the record, Google cracked SHA-1 in 2017.  https://www.theverge.com/2017/2/23/14712118/google-sha1-collision-broken-web-encryption-shattered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recomputing *secret* from *SHA-1(secret || suffix1)* (for any known value of *suffix*) would constitute a preimage attack. No preimage attack faster than luck is currently known for SHA-1 ("luck" works in average effort *2<sup>160</sup>* for SHA-1, i.e. totally infeasible). You won't get the *secret* value.

However, if your goal is to compute *SHA-1(secret || suffix2)* then that one may be possible, depending on the value of *suffix2*. It is called the [length extension attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack). Namely, *suffix2* must begin with *suffix1*, followed by some padding bits which depend on the length of *secret || suffix1*; after these bits (which you do not choose), you can put whatever data you want. In that sense, *suffix2* is partially controlled by the attacker.

Length extension attacks are sufficient to show that *SHA-1(secret || data)* is a poor [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code), and [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) should be used instead (all of this applies equally well with the SHA-2 functions, by the way).

Now if you do not want to put any constraint on *suffix2*, then this is going to be hard. The effect of *secret* boils down to an unknown 160-bit state at the start of the second block. I don't have time this morning to work this out mathematically, but my intuition is that finding that state value from the output of *SHA-1(secret || suffix1)* would be equivalent to exploring a cycle in the permutation incarnated by the [SHACAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHACAL) block cipher with *suffix1* as key (assuming *suffix1* + padding fits in one block). Since SHACAL is supposed to be a "good" block cipher, this permutation should behave as if chosen randomly among the set of possible permutation of a space of size *2<sup>160</sup>*, meaning that the cycle should have, on average, a length close to *2<sup>80</sup>*. This again implies a cost too high to do it in practice.

Note that being able to do what you try to achieve would not contradict the properties of SHA-1 as a "good hash function" (resistance to collisions, preimages and second preimages). It does not mean that we don't care about it, but it highlights why hash functions and random oracles are not exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! If you ever find the time to work out the maths please do. 2**80 really is quite a large number!

Comment: Google cracked SHA-1 in 2017.